# Setting an environment variable from within the sbt shell

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt

I would like to be able to set an environment variable from within the interactive sbt shell, and I can't seem to find a way to do that. (I have looked on the official sbt docs as well as on stackoverflow without success).

I want to make it clear that **I don't want** to have to set this environment variable in the `build.sbt` file, but rather be able to change it on the fly on my interactive sbt shell session, so that the environment variable is used for the next sbt commands I run.

For example, I would like to be able to do something like (from within the sbt shell):

```
> set_environment_variable("foo", "foo_value")
> `mymodule`/run
> (... program runs and completes)
> set_environment_variable("foo", "another_foo_value")
> `mymodule`/run
```

Is this possible? And if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think so. The problem is that `sbt` is running as the child process under the shell that invoked it, and a child process isn't _supposed_ to be able to modify the parent.

Comment: @jwvh I actually don't want to alter the parent shell. I just want to set the value of my environment variable for future commands executed in the sbt shell itself. Maybe my example was misleading. I'm going to modify it a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using sbt `0.13.15` the only thing I've found which has worked for me is to use `eval`.

```
> eval System.setProperty("foo", "foo_value")
> `mymodule`/run
> ...
> eval System.setProperty("foo", "another_foo_value")
> `mymodule`/run
```