# How can I set env variable from within sbt shell?

Tags: scala, environment-variables, sbt

I want to run my application through the sbt console by passing some custom env variables.

```
$ sbt
$ sbt> run MyApp
```

How should I pass env variable to the run command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting an environment variable from within the sbt shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327218/setting-an-environment-variable-from-within-the-sbt-shell)

Comment: Not really, because it sets the property and not the env.

Comment: Consider `export MY_ENV=foo; sbt run`

Comment: I am already inside the sbt shell.